# rails validates_format_of with IP addresses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemodel

I'm allowing a user to enter IP addresses in an input field which may be of different types delimited by a comma, such as (in no particular order):

`192.168.1.1,192.168.2.1-25,10.10.10.0/24,192.168.1.2`

This 'string' would get saved in my DB under `device.ips_to_scan`.

I want to `validates_format_of` on these, but am finding it a little difficult to write a regex that seems to work in rails, while it does work on regex101 (https://regex101.com/r/nf2bnM/1):

```
 validates_format_of :ips_scan, with: /\A([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(\/([1-2][0-9]|[0-9]|3[0-2]))?(-([0-9]{1,3}))?,?\Z/i, on: :update
```

**This one is expected to fail:**

```
Started PUT "/devices/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-02-19 22:03:15 -0500
Processing by DevicesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"EQCFG6/xoJHtP6Nd3oqaYRW6mypfEoCMrnio1yj6loP+KtvjgLZ9Gmhb0oTwCjD0RGH+qQuctZFVIvF5HBJcGw==", "device"=>{"ips_scan"=>"192.168.1.1,192.168.2.1-25,a.b.c.d", "ips_exclude"=>"10.10.10.1"}, "commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"2"}
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Device Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  "devices".* FROM "devices" WHERE "devices"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.5ms)  ROLLBACK
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/devices/2/edit
Completed 302 Found in 47ms (ActiveRecord: 12.1ms)
```

**...But this one should have worked:**

```
Processing by DevicesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"JJfmT/0l5MEDc+gUH/WHHp3bbgyzjGa0xTzaXM3E/WHLvbi30mI5SoYXmc0xdS2LzAALj+cCU6k+ZoPy+Sw3+Q==", "device"=>{"ips_scan"=>"192.168.1.1,192.168.2.1-25,192.168.1.2", "ips_exclude"=>"10.10.10.1"}, "commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"2"}
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Device Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "devices".* FROM "devices" WHERE "devices"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.6ms)  BEGIN
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.6ms)  ROLLBACK
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/devices/2/edit
Completed 302 Found in 17ms (ActiveRecord: 3.5ms)
```

Last thing I can think of, is that I do have strong parameters, but I'm permitting `ips_scan`, so that this shouldn't be an issue:

```
def update
  if @device.update(device_params)
    flash[:notice] = 'Successful update'
    respond_with :edit, :device
  else
    flash[:warning] = 'Unable to update'
    respond_with :edit, :device
  end
end

private def device_params
  params.require(:device).permit(:token, :ips_scan, :ips_exclude)
end
```

I'm hoping you rubyist's out there have a eloquent solution.  The first thought that comes to mind is that I have to `split` the string, and check each element sequentially to ensure it matches instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method in your custom validator to check an IP address

```
require 'ipaddr'

def valid_ip_addr?(ip_addr)
  IPAddr.new(ip_addr)
  true
rescue IPAddr::InvalidAddressError => _error
  false
end
```

Comment: This is a much more eloquent solution, however it doesn't account for if the user passes in an IP range like `10.10.10.1-25`

Answer (score 0):

While I'm still open to a nice eloquent one-liner within the Model itself, I was able to get this working through creating a concern:

> models/concerns/ip_validator.rb

```
class IpValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    ips = record.ips_scan.split(',')
    ips.each do |ip|
      /([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(\/([1-2][0-9]|[0-9]|3[0-2]))?(-([0-9]{1,3}))?/ =~ ip
      record.errors.add(:ips_scan, ' is not valid') unless $LAST_MATCH_INFO
    end
  end
end
```

The call in my model now looks like:

```
validates :ips_scan, :ips_exclude, ip: true, on: :update
```